# Alternative way to transfer many files between two Android phones with many restrictions

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, file-transfer, xiaomi

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 in terrible condition (charging port broke, power button broke etc). I am using a battery of another S3 to power it whenever needed. I have a whole lot of files to transfer (photos, docs etc) to my new phone Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 (I guess it's not available where you guys are, but still).

- I cannot use a USB cable. (Charging port broke.)
- Bluetooth is WAY too slow for so many files, and drains the battery which cannot be charged while using the phone (it's another S3's battery).
- I cannot use my laptop as a medium because my laptop does not have Bluetooth (my fault, long story).
- Redmi Note 3 does not have NFC.
- My Redmi does not have a SIM card yet.

I can't figure out what to do. Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: Any reason why cloud storage (Google Drive, Dropbox, Box, OneDrive, etc) isn't available from your S3?

Comment: Those have a file limit don't they? I have a huge amount of files (from 4 years of usage). Also, uploading that much data will also take time - wouldn't Bluetooth be faster anyway?

Comment: @MorrisonChang What you said is still a good option, though - maybe I can try uploading limited files at a time. I'll have to look into it and see if my S3 battery can handle it.

Comment: Local WiFi available? What about using the WiFi hotspot function on one of them, and have the other connecting to it? Or use some [apps that offer WiFi-Direct for data transfers between two devices](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_wifi_misc#group_433)?

Comment: Estimated total size of all these files?

Comment: Thanks for all your responses. I am having trouble keeping the battery of the phone alive (it's charging port broke and I am borrowing batteries) and will try out everything here. I don't know when I'll succeed - Sorry for the delay.

Comment: Estimated total size is around 8 GB.

Answer (score 1):

try shareit application from playstore installing in both mobiles. it works on wifi and you can send your data very fastly. mobiles connect to eachother using wifi but desnot need to connect to any other wifi network so no need to worry about privacy

Answer (score 0):

You can use Asus Share Link application (even on non ASUS branded devices) or similar application from competitors to do send files by direct Wi-Fi or passing by a Wi-Fi enabled access point.